# An array converting question

Tags: javascript

I have an array below,

```
var array = {
    "Id":[1,2,3],
    "Name":["one","two","five"],
    "row":[8,9,7]
}
```

but I want to transform it into

```
var array2 = 
{"data":
    [
    {"Id":1,"Name":"one","Row:8"},
    {"Id":2,"Name":"two","Row:9"},
    {"Id":3,"Name":"five","Row:7"},
    ]
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
// make sure the new object is initialized
var array2 = { data: [] };
// Count the number of items in array.Id and start iterating
for (var i=0,t=array.Id.length; i < t; i++) {
   // Note that array.Id = [1,2,3] does not result in corresponding keys
   // array.Id[0] corresponds to value 1!
   array2.data.push({
       Id: array.Id[i],
       Name: array.Name[i],
       Row: array.Row[i]
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array2 = {data: []};
for (i in array.Id) {
    array2.data.push({
        Id: array.Id[i],
        Name: array.Name[i],
        row: array.row[i]
    });
}
```

Didn't test it

Comment: No, it's not. array[i] is meaningless here

Answer (score 0):

it's not an array. it's an object.

```
var myArr = [1,2,3]; //Array definition


var myObj = {test:"1",test2:"2"}; //Object Definition



var array = [1,[1,2,3]]; // multidimensional array
```

Comment: but,actually,object is a multidimensional array too?

Comment: no they are not. I've added multidimensional array example. arrays are different from objects.

Comment: Arrays in Javascript are a specific type of object, with auto-incrementing numbers for keys. You're using objects, but not arrays.

Comment: Pretty much everything in JavaScript is technically an object, *including arrays*. Still, it is pretty clear what the OP wants to do and this answer is not *really* an answer.

Comment: yes I know that this isn't an answer, but I wanted the author to know that arrays are not normal objects.

Comment: @Headshot, I understand :) It's probably better suited as a comment on his original question then.